# Sent emails using postfix receives in spam folder of Outlook and Yahoo

Tags: amazon-ec2, postfix-mta, mail-server

I have configured `postfix` and dovecot for my mail server in an AWS instance. I have also configured `opendkim`, `opendmar`c and `spf`, `mx` record in DNS provider(Route 53). When I checked with `mx` toolbox, all my records are shown as published.

I am able to send emails to gmail server and it receives in inbox of gmail. But problem is that in Outlook,Hotmail and Yahoo sent emails receives in spam or junk folder.

Please let me know a solution for this.

Comment: Do you have source of received email from hotmail or yahoo showing confirmed dkim, dmarc, and spf lookups?

Comment: @Stephan I have attached raw message from yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

```
X-Apparently-To: jersenmathew27@yahoo.com; Mon, 28 Jan 2019 11:44:45 +0000
Return-Path: <smtpstguser@stg-smtp.biz-message.kddi.com>
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 
Received-SPF: pass (domain of stg-smtp.biz-message.kddi.com designates 
52.193.220.147 as permitted sender)
X-YMailISG: 4t8etRsWLDvZ7x5AI9CD815_v7p2_ZAC9kyYY6k8z5osoGDK
3EZpHfeIa3PwlPzmBDfarDnD8uv7oHH8mmDR4XkvY3rPnJu78bUNTT8Czmih
Ai1Fmc27BL5HzMxceZ.DZOEqq7CMgj8nMr1vHS.Z9NOg_KFS7UehLWsT1Q89
c.8GFF0XXPZTY7U53Oq2Xz3yVSZSOhcnuvbScKEftaWOytg_Csi.viyLJ1zV
7uhhoMqr83I8zhxfWg8y196JYBLXvYsLrVtujWWaBDtOHGR4ah0HEolIYn7.
kc5oq4qNQNgysyvcS.ZZa2AHHhWgMwm67OHaXLq.MljfzhS.I.Xtm7nU5YYE
CBYnUT69Dbe7UkwTtBAKTxw7hrfXWBid5gHgvufeVAZnqk2tCr.O0R9x461H
HzMrXdJLlU5diT74aRI0VqCnvBre4VTnUxvrV1xFlsRWW_.fdjAmTz7XSctu
1L8ExGF4rKUroGpqf6DxkERHK4iaChqX27I1ozCf5s.ilP9.D64EE7gru3qk
V_0vx1jltO4212gT4O.993ylN0qdjMaPzcnL_6Wm1pyfMLznn1ALCQKyc6pr
Ix6vZlULysOFU39UM2Q5mqQ36Ac6OX19E7yLMOquSdkDj5f6q2DhlT_T54qk
Qk7Qel9OlblgSeM5pARb6u6uTsUzWev3Tu2Dn__H3Cr0uXcoe834OzWkm6Cf
aj2aNaZvShsrEa0nfxc6RdbAK6WB5nqD2hlHR11iK3F63UTq4LvZeCp.BD_z
XvIeJQpyMwSrmJORuFl835XzUoUIlCuX45bZtCHBxiohVVhy.O6Z2Fa_UWid
M0XnR3OZMHiz6CN3G.YQMMZyXhTIzRtAq9Z1UouTotbKZMmiChatwerCmi6J
n_DImNI3TP3dxZ.sugzFUr4w9FnYQlNKzXrnlTKKvS9d.86BNatm1Dy4L1Of
rbByWuHd6cJeS7LtzQT0_lm705gTde5_j5ttkTM7Nd0r5IU1JYKw44CJ
X-Originating-IP: 
Authentication-Results: mta4050.mail.gq1.yahoo.com 
header.i=@stg-smtp.biz-message.kddi.com; header.s=mail; dkim=pass (ok)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  
by mta4050.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Mon, 28 Jan 2019 11:44:45 +0000
Received: from smtp-server-stg (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by stg-smtp.biz-message.kddi.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 0429B60DF3
for <jersenmathew27@yahoo.com>; Mon, 28 Jan 2019 20:44:44 +0900 (JST)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 stg-smtp.biz-message.kddi.com 0429B60DF3
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
d=stg-smtp.biz-message.kddi.com; s=mail; t=1548675884;
bh=YdlV/Z8go67IC2xzWq7eIGd3tqSaYlFrIdNjJJ5jJNw=;
h=Date:From:To:Subject:From;
b=Bf5DKJjRyEFGHux8C37/APhektcAhk6cW7pVUS2+X/gB2anXYa1I8kRdxlB/P74jQ
 LMzFp87fBENYHt9B1TglN4ew5I9CJUoLBIdC/uI5L6i/7zXuTC+rVp4tLI+5c/9rfa
 cXpA8wZISTlLB+o9DJYuTvx9N+yzP3n0HCfVU0qyK
```